# $@ blank in Bash script which is ENTRYPOINT unless --entrypoint

Tags: bash, docker

Consider the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial-20170802
RUN (echo '#!/bin/bash'; echo 'echo "args: $@"') > /run.sh && chmod a+x /run.sh
ENTRYPOINT /run.sh
```

Using Docker 1.12.6 (on an Ubuntu Zesty host, in case it matters), if I

```
docker build -t entrypoint-test .
docker run --rm entrypoint-test a b c
```

I just get

```
args:
```

In other words, `$@` is not working. However this seems to indicate that the shell script itself is OK:

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash entrypoint-test /run.sh a b c
```

producing

```
args: a b c
```

as expected. Even stranger,

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint /run.sh entrypoint-test a b c
```

works. Note that compared to the original command, I am doing nothing but overriding the `ENTRYPOINT` directive with an `--entrypoint` of the same value. So why would that make it work?

I cannot see anything in [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) that would suggest argv would be blank in some cases, perhaps involving `#!` executable scripts.

Adding

```
cat /proc/$$/cmdline
```

to the shell script confirms that the arguments are not being passed along unless `--entrypoint` is used:

```
/bin/bash^@/run.sh^@a^@b^@c^@
```

vs.

```
/bin/bash^@/run.sh^@
```

Answer (score 4):

https://serverfault.com/a/647790/144361 pointed me in the right direction. [These docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) explicitly note that the “shell form” does not accept arguments. The following syntax works:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```